# After updating xamarin forms, stacklayouts inside relativelayouts are not laying out properly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Some of my `StackLayouts` are wrapping to their content width/height rather than using the constraints given to them when adding them to a `RelativeLayout`. An example of this happening is my navigation bar. I create it like this

```
var leftButtonLayout = new StackLayout
{
  Children = { _sceneMainToolsView.MenuButton, _sceneTitle },
  Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
  BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(Colours.Orange),
  HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
  Spacing = 8
};
```

I add it to my relative layout

```
_layout.Children.Add(leftButtonLayout,
  Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => 0),
  Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => 0),
  Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => p.Width),
  Constraint.RelativeToParent(p => NavBarHeight));
```

And later I set my ContentView's `Content` Property

```
Content = _layout;
```

This has been happening since I updated my xamarin forms nuget package to 2.3.0.49 (necessary to use certain dll's). Does anybody know why this is happening or how to fix it? I'm testing on Android 4.4.2 (kitkat) and compiling using 6.0 (marshmallow).

Comment: What you're doing seems to be correct. I'd try to file a bug on [Xamarin's Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/).